# How to keep Powerbuilder from prepending table owner to table name (Postgres / PB 10.5)

Tags: postgresql, powerbuilder

I am connecting to a Postgresql database from Power Builder 10.5, using ODBC on Windows 7.. and I notice that PB prepends the table owner to the table name, eg if I am connected to the database as "user", it will format the query as "SELECT x, y, z FROM user.tablename".

This makes sense in Sybase, but does not work correctly in postgres, where schemas and users are a separate thing.

I tested by creating a postgres schema with the same name as the user, and then putting the tables within the schema.  So, when PB used "username.tablename" postgres interpreted it as "schemaname.tablename" and this worked.. but it was just a test and not a useable solution.

It says in the docs that if the table owner is the same as the current user, PB will not prepend the owner, but if they don't match, it will.  But in my test program, I see is the opposite: If UID is the same as the owner name, it DOES prepend, if they don't match, it doesn't.

Here's my connect code:

```
sqlca.DBMS = "ODBC"
sqlca.userid  = "pblearn"
sqlca.dbpass = "pblearn"
string ls_DSN = "PBLEARN"

string ls_connect = "ConnectString='"
ls_connect += "DSN=" + ls_DSN + ";"
ls_connect += "UID=" + sqlca.userid + ";"
ls_connect += "PWD=" + sqlca.dbpass + "'"

sqlca.dbparm = ls_connect + ", SQLQualifiers=0"
connect;
```

My schemas are pblearn and public (default).. and two users "pblearn" and "pblearn2".  If I connect with pblearn, prepend happens and I see the tables in pblearn (owner of the tables) schema, if I use pblearn2, the username is not prepended and I see the tables in public schema.

How can I get PB to either not prepend the username, or to prepend a consistent schema name regardless of user?

Thanks

Comment: Which user owns the tables in those schemas?

Comment: In both schemas (public and pblearn), the tables are owned by pblearn.  What I did was to create a table with the same name in both schemas with different data in them, so when I Retrieve in the datawindow it's easy to see which schema it is accessing.

Comment: In PB when setting up the database profile there is a System tab.  If you put your table owner in then check the Preview tab you can see the syntax needed for the connection.  Not sure if this will work for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your database section of the `PBODB105.INI` used by your installation, add the following property :

```
PBTableOwner='NO'
```

From the documentation :

> ;PBTableOwner='NO' - do not qualify table names, default is 'YES'

EDIT :

If no sections exist for a particular connection then Powerbuilder
runs as an ODBC compliant client and extensions that might be
available cannot not be utilized. The search algorithm for the
entries is:

```
IF section and entry for are present current datasource
THEN use entry value
ELSE IF section corresponding to DBMS_Name Driver_Name exist 
THEN use entry value if it exist 
ELSE IF section corresponding to DBMS_Name exist 
THEN use entry value if it exist
```

SECTION  Headings

- **DataSource_Name** (None are in ini file by default but if you need to override the more general setting of DBMS_Driver or DBMS_Name you would put in a data source specific section
- **DBMS_Name Driver_Name** (Driver_Name is stripped of .dll extension)
- **DBMS_Name** (DBMS name returned by the SQLGetInfo call)

So the easiest way to add a section for your Postgres installation is to make a section named with your current datasource name

Comment: Thanks a lot.. In my PBODB105.INI there is no section for postgres (but the application works anyway??).  I've found good examples of PBODB entries for postgres but what I can't figure out is how to name the entry so that it will be used.. or what config changes I need for that...  If you have a hint for me??  I see  that your answer is almost definitely right but will be responsible and get it working first before I accept...  Thanks!